# Help me understand this Midrash Talpiot about finding lost objects

Tags: tzedakah-charity, nedarim-shevuot, lost-and-found

https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33215&st=&pgnum=27

I understand you have to make a vow that you will give שמן in honour of R Meir. Also that it may not work if someone already found the item or if its clothing and its in another place.

My questions:
What is למאור ? Do I make the vow in front of a candle?
What is שמן למאור? Am I meant to be donating oil?

FYI I have already tried the basic sgula of R Meir and it did not work so Im moving on to this more advanced one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the person who sent this to me.

It means to sponsor the electricity bill for your shul. When it was written they had someone sponsor the candles for Shul but nowadays this same terminology is used and is referring to the electricity bill. Either a Shul or a Beit Midrash.

Perhaps the mods can add a special tag here so that this may serve as a resource for people who lost valuable objects.